# Jquery Tab Validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have done a page with jQuery tabs. Now I am trying to validate this using jQuery Validation plugin.

On submitting the form it's validating only the selected tab. The inactive tabs are not validated at all.. please help.

Comment: Can you please provide some code?

Comment: have you got any answer !!? because I am in same situation/trouble

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing ajax loading of your content, this would be valid as it only loads the page that's in view at that time and the rest of the content goes away.  I had such an issue and solved it by moving all my content into the main page that calls the tabs, then declared the tabs on divs, not on external pages.  As an added bonus, you can jump back and forth between tabs and not lose values in your form via this method.

edit: it's also possible that your form doesn't span all the content you're trying to validate.  If you apply the validate selector to the form itself, it could be missing elements you intend to validate.  Again, code is needed to know for sure.

More detail (code) is needed to ensure this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like since version 1.9, :hidden elements are ignored by default.
The code that worked for me was setting:

```
  $.validator.setDefaults({
    ignore: ""
  });
```